How many ways are there to form an (unordered) collection of four pairs of two people chosen from a group of 30 people?
Could someone please provide some insight on this:

How many ways are there to form an (unordered) collection of four pairs of two
people chosen from a group of 30 people?

My approach is select 2 from the 30, then 2 from 28 and so on. Then divide by 4! since order doesn't matter. Yielding:
$$\frac{\operatorname{nCr}\left(30,2\right)\cdot\operatorname{nCr}\left(28,2\right)\cdot\operatorname{nCr}\left(26,\ 2\right)\cdot\operatorname{nCr}\left(24,2\right)}{4!}$$
However my textbook gives this answer:
$$\operatorname{nCr}\left(30,2\right)\cdot\operatorname{nCr}\left(28,2\right)\cdot\operatorname{nCr}\left(26,\ 2\right)\cdot\operatorname{nCr}\left(24,2\right)$$
Could someone please confirm if dividing by 4! is valid or not? I do not understand why we wouldn't do this.

Not that this is what you are asking, but I think the question is poorly phrased.  It's not at all clear to me that the couples are required to be disjoint.   Given the official answer (in spite of the confusion as to ordered/unordered) it seems clear that they are, but I don't think that's obvious from the problem statement.

For what it's worth, your interpretation is more easily implemented as $~\displaystyle \binom{30}{8} \times 7 \times 5 \times 3 \times 1.~$  That is, after the $~8~$ people are chosen, arbitrarily index them as P-1, P-2, ..., P-8.  There are $~7~$ choices for P-1.  Let P-k denote the remaining lowest index, which will either be P-2 or P-3.  Then, there are $~5~$ choices for P-k, and so forth.

You are correct in dividing by $4!$ as the collection of pairs is unordered.
The answer provided by the textbook is for the collections of ordered pairs, so it is a mistake.
